# Java ME - Поймать нажатие на решетку

Tags: java, j2me

Для разнообразия пишу игрушку под телефон один старый. Интересно как получить событие нажатия на решетку? В игре bounce через клавиатуру вводится чит код, значит это реально. Как?

Comment: Так же, как и событие нажатия на любую другую клавишу. Вы не знаете как сделать обработчик или не знаете код решётки или в чём у вас проблема-то?

Comment: И то и другое) спасибо, что откликнулись

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо ловить в `Canvas` в методе `keyPressed()` нажатие клавиши `KEY_POUND`

Пример реализации [например здесь](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0430__J2ME/Canvaskeypressedandkeytypedevents.htm)

P.S. Еле вспомнил свою J2ME молодость :)

Comment: Вот это да! Спасибо!! Как же прикольно писать под эти телефоны )) Особенно когда все детство провёл в этих джарниках